# No logro subir la imagen a el storage de firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

Cordial saludo, requiero su ayuda,

Al intentar subir la imagen al Storage de firebase en mi app en FLUTTER me genera este mensaje.

Muchas gracias

Comparto el codigo,

```
void uploadStatusImage() async {
  if (validateAndSave()) {

  //Subir la foto al storage de firebase

  FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
  Reference ref = storage.ref().child("image1" + 
  DateTime.now().toString());
  UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(sampleImage);

  var imageUrl = uploadTask.then((res) {
    res.ref.getDownloadURL();
  });

  // var imageUrl = await (await uploadTask).ref.getDownloadURL();
  url = imageUrl.toString();
  url;

  // Guardar el post en firebase database: realtime database
  saveToDataBase(url);

  //Regresar al Home
  Navigator.pop(context);
}
```

}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buenas, es recomendable que tanto el código como el error estén escritos y no sea una imagen.

Comment: Manuel, ya agregue el codigo para que por favor se pueda validar mejor, quedo atento, muchas gracias

Comment: Se me ocurre que esto:  url = imageUrl.toString(); puede estar mal, ya que ese toString, se ejecuta sobre un futuro, el cual debería de esperarse. Aunque no estoy seguro, ya que el código de la imagen y el código posteado son diferentes